# Delete row: not matching with other columns

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
Type    Brand A Brand B
Type A  ID A    ID AA
Type B  ID A    ID AA
Type A  ID B    ID BB
Type B  ID B    ID BB
Type B  ID C    ID CC
Type A  ID C    ID DD
Type B  ID D    ID EE
Type A  ID D    ID FF
```

I want drop or eliminate rows data two brand column and ype column (must be couple)

my desire result looks like this:

```
Type    Brand A Brand B
Type A  ID A    ID AA
Type B  ID A    ID AA
Type A  ID B    ID BB
Type B  ID B    ID BB
```

thank you in advance

Comment: On what basis are we trying to delete the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test if number of unique values by [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and also count by [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) per groups is pair (`2`):

```
g = df.groupby(['Brand A','Brand B'])['Type']
df = df[g.transform('nunique').eq(2) & g.transform('size').eq(2)]
print (df)
     Type Brand A Brand B
0  Type A    ID A   ID AA
1  Type B    ID A   ID AA
2  Type A    ID B   ID BB
3  Type B    ID B   ID BB
```

If need test `Type A` and `Type B`:

```
g = df.groupby(['Brand A','Brand B'])['Type']
df = df[g.transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['Type A','Type B'])) & g.transform('size').eq(2)]
print (df)
     Type Brand A Brand B
0  Type A    ID A   ID AA
1  Type B    ID A   ID AA
2  Type A    ID B   ID BB
3  Type B    ID B   ID BB
```